# JavaScript replace all ignoring case sensitivity

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace all the occurences of a value in a string and with another value

what I have so far is

```js
var result = "Cooker Works" 
var searchterm = "cooker wor";

searchterm.split(" ").forEach(function (item) {
   result = result.replace(new RegExp(item, 'g'), "<strong>" + item + "</strong>");
});
    
console.log(result)
```

The result I am after should look like

```
result = "<strong>Cooker</strong> <strong>Wor</strong>s";
```

I am having problems handling the case, Is there any way I can ignore this and still get the result I am after

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will get the result you want using capture groups and the `i` (ignoreCase) modifier. You can reference the capture group with `$1`.

```js
var result = "Cooker Works";
var searchterm = "cooker wor";

searchterm.split(" ").forEach(function(item) {
    result = result.replace(new RegExp(`(${item})`, 'ig'), "<strong>$1</strong>");
});

console.log(result)
```

See MDN for more details: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter

Comment: Mind = blown. How has this been a thing for 5 years and I'm just finding out about it now?

Answer (score 7):

You need to use `i` modifier for *case-insensitive* matching

```
new RegExp(item, 'ig')
```

```js
var result = "Cooker Works"
var searchterm = "cooker wor";

searchterm.split(" ").forEach(function(item) {
  var matchs = result.match(new RegExp(item, 'ig'));
  if (matchs.length)
    result = result.replace(new RegExp(item, 'ig'), "<strong>" + matchs[0] + "</strong>");
});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Did you notice that this will not give the result he is looking for?

Comment: your code will not work in following case, result = "Cooker Works cooker"

Comment: @Puneet, Agreed

Answer (score 2):

You need to add case-insensitive modifier. do something like this:

```js
    var result = "Cooker Works" 
    var searchterm = "cooker wor";
    
    searchterm.split(" ").forEach(function (item) {
    result = result.replace(new RegExp('(' + item + ')', 'gi'),'<strong>$1</strong>');
    });
    console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

**This will solve your problem**

```js
var result = "Cooker Works" 
var searchterm = "cooker wor";

searchterm.split(" ").forEach(function (item) {
     result = result.replace(new RegExp(item, 'ig'), "<strong>" + result.match(new RegExp(item, 'ig')) + "</strong>");
});

console.log(result)
```